# Rotate image by 90 degrees using Jqueryrotate plugin

Tags: jquery

I have the following code and i am getting an error message stating object doesn't support that property on the line where i try to rotate the images ($("#img1").rotate(90);). So wanted to know if i am doing anything wrong?Just banging my head with this error since morning....Can any one pls advise?

$(document).ready(function() { 
$("#img1").rotate(90); });

i have put the id of the image tag as "img1".

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the jqueryrotate script is not being loaded properly.

Comment: I have included the plugin <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jQueryRotate.2.1">

Comment: Is it being loaded after jQuery? Are you sure the browser can find the script?

Comment: I would expect the correct link to be <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jQueryRotate.2.1.js"> (notice i added .js to the end there)

Answer (score 1):

This may be a stupid question but are you including the jqueryrotate library?

http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

Comment: Yes i have included jQueryRotate.2.1 in the script

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the selector is working?

```
        $Items = $("#img1");

        if ($Items.length == 0)
            alert("Not Found!");
```

Comment: Hi I get length of 1 when i test it with $Items.length

Comment: Then the other poster's are probably correct and the js rotate file may not be loading correctly.  Do you get rotate in the intellisense?